Loading CSV files with double quotes in field values via Oracle Loader External table
Requesting your help and expertise on the below:
Oracle DB 19c on UNIX server
Requirement:
CSV files come in on a daily basis in a Unix directory (where the database resides) and gets loaded to a database table. Record terminator is LF (Unix). The CSV file can have linefeeds (LF) in a string, and also special characters. If there are embedded commas as part of the field, they are enclosed with double quotes. Skip header row. Skip loading rows with all null fields. The desired output would be to get all the records loaded in this example CSV file. All these CSV files in real world get read through External table before being appended to a Main table.
CSV File (dummy_test_file.csv):
EMP_ID,EMP_DEPT,EMP_NAME,EMP_SAL,EMP_COMMENTS
101,Accounting,John Doe,78000,None
MM202,Finance,Jack N Doe,80000,"PTO, OOO"
303,Finance,"Dunham, Melissa",98000,N/A µóíé ``é
404,Info Tech,O'Connor A.,,
Z505,""Infra Services,Joe Miller,67000,,Infra
606,""R&D"" Info. Sec - Commercial,Jack Miller,68000,""
707,""Accounting & Offices"",M'ria Flo,55000,20-PPES
808,"- State S7 -20 - 24
- state S3 ,//- 29 - 32
- INC - 49 - 56 (14.004% inic)
- SD",Scala F. Mora,88000,Static
909,",",Nem Rogers,66500,Cambridge - MA
,,,,

1101,,,,""1""
AX2202,Finance,Meryl Jane,110000,STEM &^%$#@!~()_+-=|:"<>?{}[]\;'./`~Pro - D.


My Attempt:
I made use of the ORACLE_LOADER External table, using FIELDS CSV WITH EMBEDDED option. It works great for loading values with special chars, and also takes care of embedded line feeds, if any, in a field. But...
The Problem:
It fails loading data for certain scenarios as described below in BAD file generated once I ran the select statement.
Bad File:
Z505,""Infra Services,Joe Miller,67000,,Infra
606,""R&D"" Info. Sec - Commercial,Jack Miller,68000,""
707,""Accounting & Offices"",M'ria Flo,55000,20-PPES
1101,,,,""1""

Scripts:
CREATE TABLE EXT_OL_DUMMY_CSV_LOAD
(
  EMP_ID        VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  EMP_DEPT      VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  EMP_NAME      VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  EMP_SAL       NUMBER,
  EMP_COMMENTS  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY MY_FILES_DIR
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( 
         RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
                          BADFILE 'dummy_test_file.bad'
                          LOGFILE 'dummy_test_file.log'
                          SKIP 1
                          FIELDS CSV WITH EMBEDDED
                              NOTRIM
                              MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
                              REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
       )
     LOCATION ( MY_FILES_DIR:'dummy_test_file.csv' )
  )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
PARALLEL 5
/

SELECT * FROM EXT_OL_DUMMY_CSV_LOAD;

Current Output: - doesn't load all records

THE ASK
Any ideas how can I load all these records making use of capabilities of Oracle Loader, without the use of preprocessor? Any other ideas are welcome too, ONLY if it cannot be handled with Oracle_Loader. Worth mentioning, I also have access to Oracle APEX packages if those are of any help solving this. Thanks in advance to anyone pitching in for help. :)
Update 1: Added the Log file:


 LOG file opened at 07/17/24 14:59:18

Total Number of Files=1

Data File: dummy_test_file.csv

Log File: dummy_test_file.log



 LOG file opened at 07/17/24 14:59:18

KUP-05010:   Warning: Intra source concurrency disabled because the input data is in CSV format with embedded record delimiters/terminators.

Bad File: dummy_test_file.bad

Field Definitions for table EXT_OL_DUMMY_CSV_LOAD
  Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  Data in file has same endianness as the platform
  Reject rows with all null fields

  Fields in Data Source: 

    EMP_ID                          CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
    EMP_DEPT                        CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
    EMP_NAME                        CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
    EMP_SAL                         CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
    EMP_COMMENTS                    CHAR (4000)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field EMP_DEPT
KUP-04037: terminator not found
KUP-04101: record 6 rejected in file /MY_FILES_DIR/dummy_test_file.csv
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field EMP_DEPT
KUP-04037: terminator not found
KUP-04101: record 7 rejected in file /MY_FILES_DIR/dummy_test_file.csv
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field EMP_DEPT
KUP-04037: terminator not found
KUP-04101: record 8 rejected in file /MY_FILES_DIR/dummy_test_file.csv
KUP-04073: record ignored because all referenced fields are null for a record
KUP-04073: record ignored because all referenced fields are null for a record
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field EMP_COMMENTS
KUP-04037: terminator not found
KUP-04101: record 13 rejected in file /MY_FILES_DIR/dummy_test_file.csv



Could you also provide the content of the log file?

@Gnqz Just added the log file as an update to the post.

Is it among your requirements to implicitly deduce the columns and not to list them in the ACCESS PARAMETERS clause?

Not exactly, I didn't put those only because they are almost the same as the external table definition. Would adding those help with the load?

for example ""Accounting & Offices"" is bad, to get quotes must be doble quotes  """Accounting & Offices"""

I'm unfamiliar with Oracle Loader, so here is an option to do it with the apex packages. Here is how to parse a CLOB with the content of the bad file:
SELECT
  col001, col002, col003, col004, col005
FROM   TABLE(
         APEX_DATA_PARSER.parse(
           p_content         => apex_util.clob_to_blob(
    p_clob => q'!Z505,""Infra Services,Joe Miller,67000,,Infra
606,""R&D"" Info. Sec - Commercial,Jack Miller,68000,""
707,""Accounting & Offices"",M'ria Flo,55000,20-PPES
1101,,,,""1""!',
    p_charset => 'AL32UTF8' )
,
           p_file_name       => 'emp.csv' /*to get the file type*/
          ,p_skip_rows       => 1 /*default 0*/
          ,p_csv_col_delimiter => ','
         )
       );
       select * from dual


There are a couple of blogs about it that should be easy to find, and the docs show all the arguments that can be used.

Thank you Koen - let me try this approach, although I haven't done it before. Preferring the Oracle Loader approach though as I'll not have to do the conversion to BLOB or CLOB.

I tried with the test data I posted and it seems to be working well. Yet, when I tried loading a large CSV with real world data, it seems to be failing for some scenario that I haven't been able to find out yet -  ORA-12899: value too large for column "SOMECOLUMN" (actual: 27, maximum: 10). Might be it wasn't able to parse the previous column properly which bled into the next which accepts only 10 chars. The same file loads fine with ORACLE_LOADER except for the failed scenarios mentioned  in BAD file.

Afraid I can't help you with that i've never used it to load large batches, just small sets of data

Thanks Koen - I appreciate you providing me additional insights of another form of data load.
